# geometry.materials[0][0].shading: Three JS property 0 is undefined

Tags: three.js, undefined

I would like to add some shading to my 3D model in Three JS.

I'm using this code:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
          loader.load("peer.js", createScene);

          function createScene( geometry ) {
            geometry.materials[0][0].shading = THREE.FlatShading;
            geometry.materials[0][0].morphTargets = true;

            var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial();
            //var material =  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0|(0xffffff*Math.random())})                
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            cube.scale.set(50, 50, 50);
            cube.position.z = -50;
            m.model.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
            m.model.add(cube);
            scene.add(m.model);
        }
```

And I'm getting the error message 'Cannot read propery 0 of undefined'.
It has something to do wit this line:  geometry.materials[0][0].shading = THREE.FlatShading; 
And I think the [0][0] has to be changed in something else, only I don't know what because I don't know what [0][0] is standing for. Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you copying outdated code from the net -- or from an outdated book? Learn from the three.js examples that work with the current version of the library r.57.

Comment: Also you should create the material before modifying the shading or other properties. Now you are first setting properties, then creating a material and creating the mesh.